# Limiting integer width in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm practicing python, I came across a situation where I wanted to limit the character width of a field but it wasn't working.(I hope I'm saying that right) I want to truncate the sum of 2 integers to 5 spaces. eg:  the sum of 88888 + 22222 has 6 characters. Is it possible to limit it to 5?

Comment: Yes it is possible, You want first five characters for the last five ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily truncate the value of these integers. Simply convert the result into a string and then use the Python index to select the first five characters:

```
>>> str(88888 + 22222)[:5]
'11111'
```

You can also convert this value back to an integer using `int()` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of decimal characters by throwing away the upper digits, you can use a remainder:

```
(88888 + 22222) % 100000
```

To do the same for a binary number, which is more commonly required, you can use a bit-wise and. Here's an example limited to 16 bits.

```
(88888 + 22222) & 0xffff
```